# python iterator through tree with list of children

Tags: python, iterator

i don't get the full grasp on python iterators,
i got an object with a list of children, and i want to iterate through this structure.
I want to  get the same behaviour as with the printall function but with an iterator.

```
    class t:
            def __init__(self, i):
                    self.l = []
                    self.a = 0
                    for ii in range(i):
                            self.a = ii
                            self.l.append(t(i-1))

            def __iter__(self):
                    return self

            def next(self):
                    for i in self.l:
                            yield i.__iter__()
                    yield self

            def printall(self):
                    for i in self.l:
                            i.printall()
                    print self.a
```

hope thats enough information, thanks

edit:

i just want to be able to iterate through all the leafs of the tree and do something with the object, i.e. when i have an instance

```
    bla = t(3)
```

i want to be able to go through every node with

```
    for x in bla:
            print x.a
```

for example. i want to be able to something with each x, 
i just have to access every child once

Comment: no, it's not enough. What do you want to see?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like you want the iterator to act as a tree traversal.  Study the `itertools` module and you can really go places.

```
from itertools import chain, imap

class t:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.children = []
  def __iter__(self):
    "implement the iterator protocol"
    for v in chain(*imap(iter, self.children)):
      yield v
    yield self.value

root = t(0)
root.children.append(t(1))
root.children.append(t(2))
root.children[1].children.append(t(3))
print list(iter(root))   # -> [1, 3, 2, 0]
print list(iter(root.children[1]))  # -> [3, 2]
```

**EDIT**: Below is the originally accepted implementation.  It has a performance problem; I would remove it, but it seems wrong to remove content that was an accepted answer.  It will fully traverse the entire structure, creating `O(N*log[M](N))` generator objects (for a balanced tree with branching factor `M` containing `N` total elements), before yielding any values.  But it does produce the desired result with a simple expression.

(The above implementation visits areas of the tree on demand and has only `O(M+log[M](N))` generator objects in memory at a time.  In both implementations, only `O(log[M](N))` levels of nested generators are expected.)

```
from itertools import chain

def isingle(item):
  "iterator that yields only a single value then stops, for chaining"
  yield item

class t:
  # copy __init__ from above
  def __iter__(self):
    "implement the iterator protocol"
    return chain(*(map(iter, self.children) + [isingle(self.value)]))
```

Comment: why unicode docstrings?  including non-ascii in the docstring would be in violation of pep-8 anyway...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy `unicode` not `str` seems more naturally the correct type to me for docstrings in Python 2.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using proposed `isingle` generator instead of single element tuple or other basic sequence? Why not `chain((self.value,), *map(iter, self.children))`?

Comment: No compelling reason to use `isingle`, it's just to illustrate the behavior of `chain` in explicit terms.  I wonder now which is faster.

Answer (score 10):

From the code you have posted, it's clear that what you are missing is *what a generator does*, and *how `__iter__` and `next` are supposed to behave*

So let's start with the iterator protocol.  an object is iterable if it returns an iterator when its `__iter__` method is called, and an iterator is an object that has a `next` method, which can be called zero or more times and should eventually raise `StopIteration`.

It's not to unusual for certain kinds of objects to be their own iterators (that have `__iter__` return `self`), but this is usually limited to objects that somehow themselves represent a position inside something.  For instance, the builtin `file` object is its own iterator, because files have an intrinsic seek position (which you can manipulate with `file.seek()` and `file.tell()`).  Other objects, which represent the totality of a collection, like `list`, return something other than themselves.

So, your tree really more sounds like the latter rather than the former;  It doesn't have a position attribute that represents which node it is on; it's all nodes at the same time, so it probably *shouldn't* have a `next()` method; `__iter__` needs to return something else.

Which gets us to generators.  When a normal function contains a `yield` statement, it is automatically not a function at all, it's a generator.  The difference is that when you call a function, it's body is executed (and possibly returns a value).  When you call a generator, it returns immedately, without executing the body at all; instead you get an *iterator*!  when you iterate over that, the function body gets called; advancing to the next `yield` each time until it finally returns.

So, putting it all together,

```
class t:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []
        self.a = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        # first, yield everthing every one of the child nodes would yield.
        for child in self.l:
            for item in child:
                # the two for loops is because there's multiple children, and we need to iterate
                # over each one.
                yield item

        # finally, yield self
        yield self
```

But, since what we're doing is iterating a sequence of iterators (and also one more thing, self), `itertools.chain` as in the accepted answer, really makes a lot of sense.

Comment: thanks for the explanation it really makes clear what i got wrong with the iterators. now also the technical side behind iterators is much clearer to me, so thanks again ^^

Answer (score 5):

My first suggestion is to change the name of your class with a more clear one following the [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It was a bit hard to manage a class name such as `t`:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.l = []
        self.a = 0
        for ii in range(i):
            self.a = ii
            self.l.append(Tree(i-1))
```

Now, you should change the `__iter__()` method to return the next element in `self`, not `self` itself - no pun intended :) The `__iter__()` method should return an iterator to the original object, not the object itself:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return next(self)
```

Now comes the hard part: the `next()` method. I always find it hard to write a recursive iterators but this is not that impossible: for each child, iterate over it and yield the iterated value:

```
def next(self):
    for i in self.l:
        for ii in i:
            yield ii
    yield self
```

Since the method is recursive, it takes care of yielding all descendants. When the `next()` method is called at a leaf node (a node without children) it will just return the node itself. OTOH, when called on a node with children, it will call itself for each children and yield the returned value. This means that it will be called by the children of the children and so on until the leaf nodes. After being called by *all* descendants of a node - which means that all descendants were yielded -, it should yield its own value, so you have to yield the original node itself.

Now your `printall()` function should work flawlessly:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
t = Tree(6)
t.printall()
```

Some final considerations:

- Always make your classes extend the `object`:

  class Tree(object)::
- I bet you want to write a `__init__()` method like the one below:

  ```
  def __init__(self, i):
      self.l = []
      self.a = i
      for ii in range(i):
          self.l.append(Tree(i-1))
  ```
- The wberry solution is better because it is more concise and, probably, more efficient. However, I think the OP is studying trees, recursion etc. so I thought a more hardcoded solution would be instructive :)