# Binary tree inorder traversal using generator

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, generator

#### Description

I want my Binary tree to be iterable so that I can loop though it to visit every node once. Also, `inorder` is a generator function which returns the `Iterator` and hence satisfies the `Iterable` contract. But my code below instead of yielding every node just yields root node which in this case is `A`. What I am doing wrong?

#### Code

```
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple('Node', 'data, left, right')

root = Node('A',
        Node('B', Node('D', None, None), Node('E', None, None)),
        Node('C', None, Node('F', None, None)))

class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.inorder(self.root)

    def inorder(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return
        if node.left is not None:
            self.inorder(node.left)
        yield node
        if node.right is not None:
            self.inorder(node.right)

bt = BinaryTree(root)            
for node in bt:
    print node.data
```

#### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916433/4260745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call `self.inorder(node.left)`, but don't do anything with the result, and as a result, the code is simply executed (well executed lazily, which means not executed), and the runtime environment continues to the next line.

You need to resolve it by propagating (i.e. *re-yielding*) the elements that are generated by the calls to `inorder`:

```
    def inorder(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return
        if node.left is not None:
            for x in self.inorder(node.left) :
                # you need to *re-yield* the elements of the left and right child
                yield x
        yield node
        if node.right is not None:
            for x in self.inorder(node.right) :
                yield x
```

Comment: if `self.inorder(node.left)` will be called then in the function definition I am doing `yield node` anyways i.e. for each call for the left and right subtree we are yielding the root of that subtree anyways. May be I am stuck with some wrong model.

Comment: @CodeYogi: no, you must understand that yield turns your method into a generator. So `self.inorder(node.left)` returns a generator. Since you don't do anything with the (lazy) generator, the continuation is disposed immedaitely.

Comment: So, the recursion doesn't works as expected with generators. If there was `print` in place of `yield` then it would have behaved correctly I think.

Comment: @CodeYogi: yes indeed, but printing stuff in functions (that are designed to calculate things), is considered bad design. Only functions that are designed to interact with users are supposed to do that.